# python multiprocessing through a pandas df

Tags: python, multiprocessing

python multiproccessing

this script creates a dataframe and defines an object then tries to fill a list with objects made with data from that dataframe.

it does this by splitting the dataframe into 2 parts and multiproccessing on each

without multiproccessing it works fine but when i try multiproccessing, even with just 1 process parts of the code seem to jump the gun and get executed early, also get executed repeatedly when they should only be executed once

[evidence of it running + it printing stuff from the end repeatedly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAR7O.png)

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class car_term(): #object to go into list 
    def __init__(self, capcode, miles,months , cmprice, fmprice ):
        self.capcode = capcode
        self.months = months
        self.miles = miles
        self.cmprice = cmprice
        self.fmprice = fmprice

df_final = pd.DataFrame({'capcode':[],'months':[],'mileage':[],'cm':[],'fm':[]})

for i in range (200): # making dataframe to get data from
    df_final = df_final.append(pd.DataFrame({'capcode':[i],'months':[random.randint(1, 12)],'mileage':[random.randint(0, 10000)],'cm':[random.randint(5, 700)],'fm':[random.randint(15, 710)]}))


all_deals=[] # this is the list i want to put my objects into
def get_car_terms(data,mdb1,all_deals1):
    all_deals1.append(car_term(mdb1['capcode'][data],mdb1['mileage'][data],mdb1['months'][data],mdb1['cm'][data],mdb1['fm'][data])) # i make the objects with the dataframe like this
all_deals1a=[]   # individual lists for each proccessor

print("yo1")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('1')
    if df_final.shape[0] != 0:
        print('2')
        df_final = df_final.reset_index(drop=True)
        print(df_final.head())
        for i in range(int(df_final.shape[0]/4)):

            ############# the problem is the get_car_terms function doesnt run below
            p1 = mp.Process( target = get_car_terms , args =(i+((df_final.shape[0]/4)*1), df_final,all_deals1a)) # each cpu sorts a quater of the dataframe into my objects list


            p1.start()

            time.sleep(10000)
            p1.join()
         #   get_car_terms(i+((df_final.shape[0]/n_cpus)*2), df_final,all_deals1a)


            print(" ppp ")
    all_deals.append(all_deals1a)   # group lists together


print("we did it")
print(len(all_deals))  # this should have 200 of my objects in it... it doesnt
for i in all_deals:
    print(len(i))
    for j in i:
        print(j.miles)
```